# Multiple stages in libGDX hides actors on back stage

Tags: java, libgdx

Using libGDX, I have two stages. One has a tiled map and a bunch of actors/sprites moving around. On top of that, I have a HUD stage, which has the score and other things.

I can see the tiled map, but the sprites aren't visible. If I don't draw the HUD stage, then I can see the sprites

The HUD is just some text in a table, so it is largely transparent.

This code:

```
Sub Main_Draw(SpriteBatch As lgSpriteBatch, ParentAlpha As Float)
    Draws the maze
    SpriteBatch.DisableBlending
    SpriteBatch.SetColorRGBA(1, 1, 1, 1)
    Maze.Draw(Stage.Camera)
    SpriteBatch.EnableBlending
    HUDStage.Draw
End Sub
```

I went so far as to remove any reference to the HUD stage, except the initialization of the stage itself, with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because libgdx recently had an API change.
Now,

```
void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
```

is called by stage's root group instead of

```
void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha)
```

Since your method does not override parent's method, it is not being called.